# PHP Parse error when including ! in php.ini

Tags: php

I'm setting the auth_password for SMTP in the php.ini file, and the password ends with an !

This causes a PHP parse error (unexpected ! in php.ini). Wrapping the password in quotes doesn't seem to work either.

Is there a way to escape this character in php.ini?

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work either... same parse error in the event viewer

Answer (score 1):

try with double quotes

```
auth_password = "YOUR_PASSWORD!"
```

Comment: That resolves the parse error, but then the SMTP server returns a failure to authenticate response.

Comment: @jaythomas it's ok if you encode your password in base64 and decode it when you need it ?

Comment: potentially.. but, would that mean decoding in every script that uses the mail function?